# How many images are needed per class to retrain CNN model such as InceptionV3 from scratch

Tags: image, tensorflow, dataset, conv-neural-network

I have to retrain the inceptionV3 model from scratch on skin lesion images. How many images per class should i use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the inceptionV3 has a model based on imagenet, so about 1000 should do. Are you sure you need to train it from scratch though?

Comment: Just need to try it once.